# React Redux Firebase Upload File Object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-storage

Trying to pass the file object to redux action and perform the function inside of an redux action, not sure its the correct way? but basically i want back downloadURL from firebase upload complete so I can show image front end.

```
createLocation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fileObject = this.state.file;

    const test = {
        fileObject
    }

    this.props.uploadImage_func(test);
}
```

and action function:

```
export function uploadImage_func(fileObject) {
    return dispatch => {
        const fileName = 'myimage';
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('test/' + fileName);
        const task = storageRef.put(fileObject);

        task.on('state_changed',
            function complete(snapshot) {
                const downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
            },
        ).then(function () {

            dispatch(attemptLogin({
                ...downloadURL
            }));

        });
    }
}
```

error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you have got an error `Invalid argument in 'put' at index 0: Expected Blob or File`. So first of all you need path exactly File or Blob. If you did right in you `createLocation` and got file object than you need not to wrap it in `const test` object more. That action causes unnecessary nesting, so just path `fileObject` as it is. And more. When you subscribe for firebase UploadTask `on` event you need to path callback functions and do it in a right order, so try to use next:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // here you could log loading information in percents but uploading is not finished yes
    console.log((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
  },
  (error) => console.log(error),
  () => {
    // And after uploading is complete you could get your download url
    console.log('Call save img', uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
  }
);
```

For more information read [documentation for Firebase Storage (Upload files)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)